# Contradiction in proof by contraposition and counterexample

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

$\forall x\in Q (\forall y \in R(y \notin Q \to \frac{x}{y} \notin Q))$

counterexample: let $x=0, y=\sqrt2$, then $\frac{0}{\sqrt2} = 0 = \frac{0}{1} \in Q$,

but by contrapositive: 
$\forall x\in Q (\forall y \in R(\frac{x}{y} \in Q \to y \in Q ))$

Suppose $\frac{x}{y}$ is rational, then $x \in Z$ and $y \in Z$ by definition of rational and any integer is rational, then y = $\frac{a}{b}$ for some integers $a$ and $b$.

So the original statement is false because there is a counterexample, but its contrapositive is true and hence the statement is true too.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your argument for the contrapositive is false. For example, $\frac{0}{\sqrt{2}}$ is rational, exactly as in your previous argument, but $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: The fact that $\dfrac x y \in \mathbb Q$ does not imply that both $x$ and $y$ are integers. It implies that we **can** express $\dfrac x y$ as a ratio between integrs; i.e. $\dfrac {0}{\sqrt 2}=0= \dfrac 0 1$.

Comment: In fact, $x$ and $y$ can even be both irrational, and $\frac{x}{y}$ nevertheless be rational, for example $x=2\sqrt{2}$ , $y=\sqrt{2}$

Comment: (+1) for the counterexample for "irrational times rational is irrational" which could be assumed without the necessary care, but we get a counterexample if the rational number is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose $\frac{x}{y}$ is rational, then $x \in Z$ and $y \in Z$ by definition of rational

False. If $x=y=\frac12$, then $\frac{x}{y}$ is rational, but $x\notin \mathbb Z$ and $y\notin\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain why this answer deserves a downvote? Is there something I wrote that is factually wrong?

Comment: I’ve upvoted, this correctly points out the flaw in OP’s reasoning.

Comment: @Brahadeesh Thank you. I guess the downvoter is too busy with other hit-and-runs to explain what he thinks is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let do this:
$$\frac{x}{y} \in \mathbb{Q} \Longrightarrow \exists q \in \mathbb{Q} : \frac{x}{y}=q \Longrightarrow x=qy \Longrightarrow y=\frac{x}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$$
That the last conclusion (dividing by $q$) is allowed **iff** $q \neq 0$, that need $x \neq 0$!